# Rounded Corners not Responding

Tags: css

I'm trying to style my corners to be rounded, but two of them don't seem to be responding, I think it has to do with the fact that I put margins and padding in and it's messing it up. Help!

```
#secondimage {
    width: 99%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you put a padding into your image here, there is some distance added *inside* the image. What you probably want is a distance outside of the image. For that, just replace `padding-left` with `margin-left` and you should be fine.

Comment: Welcome :) If you feel that the question has been answered, please mark the best answer to your question as solution (hitting the sign symbol)

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
[  <img class="myimage" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-8.jpg">  }
```

CSS:

```
body{background-color:#cccccc;}
img.myimage{width:50%;border-radius:20px}
```

Please refer to this jsfiddle code:

https://jsfiddle.net/jak1tcaj/5/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes